# Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters: (Ganache)

Tags: truffle, evm, ganache

Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
- host       > 127.0.0.1
- port       > 7545
- network_id > *
Please check that your Ethereum client:
- is running
- is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
- is accessible over the network
- is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)

Truffle v5.3.9 (core: 5.3.9)
Node v16.3.0

**This is from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLahq4qyors&t=590s**

AND yes my ganache is opened , my truffle-config.json is configured properly with correct port and all tried other solutions from this work but unfortunately it did not work

My config

````
require('babel-polyfill');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
      evmVersion: "petersburg"
    }
  }
}```
````